# Developing a graphic that highlights differences in time between items, task and sub task times

Tags: data-visualisation

I'd like to make a visualization that shows the differences in total timelines and variability to complete a task. In total, there are 20 of these items, each with a different total and step times. They all have some variability to them. The "items" are not related to each other, but the "steps" happen sequentially.

```
Item (20 in total):
Item 1: step 1 (1-3 years), step 2 (1-2 years), step 3 (3-6 years): total: 5-11 years
```

So far, my thoughts are to do a row bar chart organized from shorter to longer as the following conceptual design. However, this design doesn't show the variability in time for each step or total time.

[image]

Which visual aid would you recommend I use to illustrate:

1. Difference in time between each item
2. Variability to complete each item and step

Comment: You may found tips on Gantt diagrams. It's a way to plan things (projects), with time, necessity of waiting for previous task, manage parallels tasks. Since it can be used for work (and so "understandable", you can find interesting presentations idea.

Comment: @Larme I don't think a Gantt chart is an answer to this as Item 1, 2, etc are not related. Also, how would you recommend I use a Gantt chart here?

Comment: It's not an answer, its just a solution where you could pick up some ideas. I'd put each step of Item1 in a new line, to clarify its time.
If steps 1 are the same for each item, maybe using same color for each step.

Comment: @Larme I think that might look too busy, don't you think with 20 items an 3 sub items, that's about 60 lines

Comment: Gantt charts can alternate on lines so you only need 2 lines per ithing regardess of item numbers. You now have room for both your things. Anyway ive had to clear 15m^2 to spread a gant chart for a car (at 14 pt text) factory so i can do the negotiation effectively. Im not a big fan of Gantt charts, anyway with this amount of data thats relatively compact its doable.